# how to use multiple order by in LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, linq, sorting

I want to use multiple order by in my query, and i am using LINQ.i am new to LINQ, i have tried the examples given on stackoverflow. but i dont know why these are not working for me , i am sure i am wrong some where. below is my situation. 
I got a project in which created using LINQ. I have little task to set order of column. Actually what is my task there is a column created date by which its ordering now. Now i want to use Createddate as well a sortOrder column for ordering.Below is code used for it:
Code in **page load** method

```
ViewState["SortDirection"] = "desc";
ViewState["SortColumn"] = "createddate";
BindAllTopics(ViewState["SortDirection"].ToString(), ViewState["SortColumn"].ToString());
```

And my **BindAllTopic** Method is as bellow:

```
 protected void BindAllTopics(string SortType, string SortColumn)
{
    var LstTopics = (from topic in Dbobj.T_topic select topic).ToList();
    if (LstTopics.Count() > 0)
    {
        if (SortType == "ASC")
        {
            LstTopics = LstTopics.OrderBy(q => q.Name).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            LstTopics = LstTopics.OrderByDescending(q => q.Name).ThenBy(q => q.SortOrder).ToList();
        }
        GrdTopics.DataSource = LstTopics.ToList();
        GrdTopics.PageSize = 25;
        GrdTopics.DataBind();

    }
    else
    {
        GrdTopics.DataSource = null;
        GrdTopics.DataBind();
        lblMsg.DisplayMessage(StatusMessages.InfoMessage, "No Topics Found.");
    }
}
```

I want to sort it firstly by sortorder which is of int type and then by Createddate.

Please help me..

Comment: You dont't need to create always  a new List with `ToList`. Once is enough if you need it at all.

Comment: What is in the sortOrder field? A column name that has to be 'ordered by' as well?

Comment: And I guess you problem is, this always sorts by `Name` then `SortOrder`? What is the question?

Comment: I want to sort it first by sortorder then by date..

Comment: `Name` is not coming from Page Load, its an attribute of `topic`

Comment: So you want to know how to convert a `string` into a `Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector` that you can pass to the OrderBy extention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want to use Dynamic Linq the following see Marc Gravell's answer below

[stackoverflow:Dynamic Linq OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

Answer (score 9):

you can add one more ThenBy() in trail

```
LstTopics.OrderByDescending(q => q.Name).ThenBy(q => q.SortOrder).ThenBy(m=>m.date)
```

Comment: I think the OP would like the order to come from the parameter

Answer (score 1):

After correction you can achieve this by Dynamic Linq

```
LstTopics = LstTopics.OrderBy(SortColumn + " " +  SortType);)
```

Comment: I think the OP would like the order to come from the parameter

Comment: @Jodrell I have corrected the answer thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @raman please see my updated answer you can achieve it by dynamic linq

Comment: I understand the down vote button is very attractive but please explain why down vote